How to log request/response using javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation?
I'd like to log all "outgoing" requests from my app. This way I can debug monitor/debug the app easier, because I usually need to reconstruct the requests in Postman/curl.
Is there a configuration for this?
obs. the real code is running inside a Wildfly instance.
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;


public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResteasyClientBuilder rcb = (ResteasyClientBuilder) ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
        ResteasyClient resteasyClient = rcb.build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = resteasyClient.target("https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/loremipsum?paragraphs=1");
        Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();

        // Is there a non-programatically (i.e. config) to log all the requests passing through javax.ws.rs lib???
        Response response = builder.get();  
      
    }
}


I assume you want to check client requests. You could do this using a ClientRequestFilter.
